# Why can't I get array key value after function?

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm calling this WordPress function:

```
get_user_meta($user->ID, "user_address");
```

And it returns array, I don't want to put this into variable but simply echo it out.

But this doesn't work:

```
get_user_meta($user->ID, "user_address")[0];
```

Why? any way to do this as one liner?

Comment: please copy paste the output of var_dump(get_user_meta($user->ID, "user_address"));

Comment: @idipous array(1) { [0]=> string(21) "Via Ruggero Bonghi 21" }

Comment: This is WordPress, huh?

Comment: Tagged/edited as such.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per function [reference](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_user_meta) you have to pass third argument `true` so that it will return you single value.

```
get_user_meta($user->ID, "user_address",true);
```

Answer (score 2):

Dereferencing an array immediately when it is returned by a function is a relatively new feature in PHP 5.4. You are most likely using 5.3 or older, in which case you cannot immediately access an element of an array returned by a function call.

> As of PHP 5.4 it is possible to array dereference the result of a function or method call directly. Before it was only possible using a temporary variable.

http://docs.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php

Comment: This is useful to know ty!

Answer (score 1):

If it's the first element you need:

```
echo array_shift(get_user_meta($user->ID, "user_address"));
```